# Select column in query based on other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table called A where records contains some column name of table B.

```
table A  
Id,              columnName     
1                col1  
2                col2  
3                col3


table B  
ID, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
```

I want to select columns of B  based on the value of table A.

Example

```
Select col1, col2, col3 
from B
```

If the record number 3 in table A were deleted the sql statement will be.

```
Select col1, col2   
from B
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a join.  A basic SQL construct.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what i want to achieve in here is the dynamic display of columns that is existing record in table A. Example. If i delete the record from table A with id 3 then the Select statement will be Select col1, col2 from B.